# Show that there is at most one prime in any $R$-class.

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

I'm learning about equivalence relations and equivalence classes and wanted to ask about an exercise. The exercise is as follows;

> Let $R$ be a relation given by
>   $$xR y \iff \exists n \in \Bbb Z: \ \ x = 2^ny. \ \ \ \ \ (x, y \in \Bbb Z)$$
>   Show that no $R$-class contains more than one prime.

I presume this has something to do with the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (i.e. uniqueness of prime factorisation).

Any $x$ that we choose has to be expressable as $x = 2^ny$ which means that, for instance, if $x = 10$ then the $R$-class of $10$ is

$$R_{10} = \lbrace y : 10 = 2^ny\rbrace.$$

The only way we can write $10$ as a product of prime factors is $2 \times 5$, so the only prime in $R_{10}$ is $5$.

Can we split this into cases, the case where $x$ is prime, so the only prime in $R_x$ is $x$ and the case where $x$ is composite, so $x$ has prime factors $2^n$ and another prime $y$?

Comment: Suppose you had two primes $p\ne q$ and for some $x$ you had $xRp$ and $xRq$. What would that imply? Can you derive a contradiction?

Comment: @RickDecker Also, if $xRp$ and $xRq$ for $p \neq q$ then we have that $\exists n \in \Bbb Z: \ \ \ x = 2^n p \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ x = 2^n q$ which implies $p = q$, which was not true by assumption. So the $R$-class can only contain $1$ prime. Is that satisfactory?

Comment: You're on the right track, but you need to start with $x=2^np = 2^mq$, since you can't immediately assume $n=m$. With that minor addition and some "without loss of generality" stuff, you'll have it.

Comment: If $n \neq m$ then $q = 2^{n-m}p$ which contradicts the fact that $p$ and $q$ are primes. So $xRp$ and $xRq \iff p = q$